# How to figure out best order to minimize completion time?

Tags: algorithms

During the mornings on a farm, goats get milked, eat breakfast, and drink in that specific order. All goats are unique, and take different times to milk, eat their breakfast, and drink their fill. Unfortunately, the farmer can only milk one goat at a time, which means that most goats have to wait a long time before they can start eating and drinking. On the other hand, there's more than enough room at the breakfast table and trough to accommodate every goat, so it's fine if more than one goat is eating or drinking at the same time. The farmer wants all the goats done with all morning rituals as soon as possible, so he needs to figure out the best order in which to milk the goats.

What I'm trying to say mathematically is that if we have a list of $n$ triplets ($m_i$, $e_i$, $d_i$), corresponding to the milking time, eating time, and drinking time of the $i$th goat, how can I find an ordering of the goats that minimizes the completion time of the last goat to complete all three activities.

Clearly milking is the main factor that must be taken into account when addressing this problem since only after milking do the goats eat and then drink. I was thinking of maybe taking the eating and drinking time as a single unit and comparing it with milking times to determine the order in which the goats should be milked depending on whether a goat has a longer milking time or a longer eating and drinking time. But I'm not sure how to write this mathematically or as an algorithm let alone if this is even efficient.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not just milk the goats with the longest combined eating and drinking times first? What makes you think *"Clearly milking is the main factor that must be taken into account when addressing this problem"*? Can you find an example?